# How can I know whether a bunch of header file are part of a "standard" C++ toolchain on Debian

Tags: debian, compiling, c++, toolchain

I have a build that fails, it complains about the lack of the following header files:

```
/usr/include/Availability.h
/usr/include/AvailabilityInternal.h 
/usr/include/_types.h
```

I know for sure that my environment must have, i.e., `stdio.h` or `cmath` (and `find / -iname stdio.h` gives me the expected answer)... but how can I know whether the above files should be here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to search for files (and what packages they belong to) is the `apt-file` command. For example, searching for stdio.h:

```
$ apt-file search /usr/include/stdio.h
libc6-dev: /usr/include/stdio.h
```

Now, I tried searching for your missing header files (on Debian 10.6) and all came up empty. However, when I removed the path and just searched for the filename, I got a few hits (I removed the html hits from the output):

```
$ apt-file search Availability.h
libclang-6.0-dev: /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/include/clang/AST/Availability.h
libclang-7-dev: /usr/lib/llvm-7/include/clang/AST/Availability.h
libclang-8-dev: /usr/lib/llvm-8/include/clang/AST/Availability.h
libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-dev: /usr/include/webkitgtk-4.0/JavaScriptCore/WebKitAvailability.h
```

Since these packages are all non-standard libraries, I'd have to assume that `Availability.h` is not *supposed* to be there, at least out-of-the-box.

Comment: In addition, most libraries describe build dependencies.  It's important to read any READMEs to ensure you have the build-dependencies met first.  If you only know the runtime dependencies, then on Debian you can usually simply append `-dev` to the package name to get the headers (i.e. `libvulkan-dev` if it links to `libvulkan1`).